# Error while updating textview on popup window on Android

Tags: java, android, popupwindow

I have an simple app which updates number each time the button is clicked. This works perfectly on a normal Activity.

However, now I have made an popup window which I want to do the same inside, but when the button inside the popup window is clicked, I get the error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
```

The error occurs when I try to update the TextView inside the popup window

Here is my simple code which again works perfectly on a normal Activity:

```
public class PopActivity extends Activity {
private WorkOutClass the_workout_class = new WorkOutClass();

private TextView repTextField, setsTextField;
private Button den_knappen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop);

    repTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.repetitionID);
    setsTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.setsID);
    den_knappen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonID);

    repTextField.setText("" + the_workout_class.getReps());
    setsTextField.setText(""+ the_workout_class.getSets());



    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8), (int)(height*.7));

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 20;

    getWindow().setAttributes(params);

    den_knappen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            the_workout_class.increaseReps();

            repTextField.setText(the_workout_class.getReps());  // Normally this works perfectly, but here i get ERROR
            setsTextField.setText(the_workout_class.getReps()); // Normally this works perfectly, but here i get ERROR

        }
    });



}}
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: does `getReps()` return integer value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your method `getReps()` is return integer value so you have to set text like below

```
 repTextField.setText(String.valueFrom(the_workout_class.getReps()));  
 setsTextField.setText(String.valueFrom(the_workout_class.getReps()));
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly! My question however is why I didnt have to do this in a normal activity?

Comment: Actually your resources and id's   are converted as integer and stored in R filer.  setText() will accept int and String as param. if param is int, it's will search on R file. that's why you getting ResourceNotFound exception